# initWithViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've seen the following method in objective c to `initWithViewController` but i haven't been able to convert it to swift :

```
- (id)initWithViewController:(UIViewController *)controller animation:(UIModalTransitionStyle)transition {
    return [self initWithViewController:controller animation:transition delay:1.0];
}
```

i tried :

```
func initWithViewController(controller:UIViewController,translation:UIModalTransitionStyle){


}
```

but i guess i am missing something in the declaration !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `AnyObject`

AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type. Any can represent an instance of any type at all, apart from function types. [See this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_503)

```
func initWithViewController(controller: UIViewController, animation transition: UIModalTransitionStyle) -> AnyObject {

  return self(viewController: controller, animation: transition, delay: 1.0)

}
```